# How can the Raku behavior on capturing group in alternate be the same as Perl

Tags: raku

How can Raku behavior on capturing group in alternate be just like Perl regex' one e.g.

```
> 'abefo' ~~ /a [(b) | (c) (d)] (e)[(f)|(g)]/
｢abef｣
 0 => ｢b｣
 2 => ｢e｣
 3 => ｢f｣
```

needed to be 'usual' Perl regex result (let index system stay Raku):

```
 $0 = 'b'
 $1 = undef
 $2 = undef 
 $3 = e
 $4 = f
```

Please give useful guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the [Synopsis 5: Regexes and Rules](https://design.raku.org/S05.html) design speculation document:

> it is still possible to mimic the monotonic Perl 5 capture indexing semantics

Inserting a `$3=` for the `(e)`:

```
/ a [ (b) | (c) (d) ] $3=(e) [ (f) | (g) ] /

andthen say 'abefo' ~~ $_

｢abef｣
 0 => ｢b｣
 3 => ｢e｣
 4 => ｢f｣
```

I've briefly looked for a mention of this in the doc but didn't see it.

So maybe we should file doc issues for mentioning this, presumably in [Capture numbers](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Capture_numbers) and [$ ($1, $2, ...)](https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-perlvar#$%3Cdigits%3E_($1,_$2,_...)).

Answer (score 5):

Unclear as to the question, but surely going back to Perl5 semantics vs Raku means changing the alternation operator.

Perl5's `|` alternation operator is one in which the "first matching alternative" wins. The equivalent alternation operator in Raku is `||`.

Raku's `|` alternation operator performs Longest Token Matching (LTM), (which roughly means if you separate your alternatives by `|`, you can spend less time ordering them by longest token to get the desired result).

[https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Alternation:_||](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Alternation:_%7C%7C)
[https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Longest_alternation:_|](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Longest_alternation:_%7C)

(As for capture numbering, maybe you can submit a request that that gets handled by the `:Perl5` or `:P5` regex adverb? See: https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Perl_compatibility_adverb )